# Visual Studio Code IntelliSense suggestions don't pop up automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I followed the install instructions in https://code.visualstudio.com, but when I write C# code, the IntelliSense suggestions don't pop up automatically, so I must trigger it by using shortcut `Command+Space`, meanwhile, the suggestions are just from the code I wrote.

Here is the screen capture below:

[image]

I checked in https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editingevolved, VSCode do support C# IntelliSense.

I don't think it is bug, maybe I did something wrong when installing VSCode. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it is a bug since it is just very very new.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OmniSharp doesn't know where your project files are. In your screenshot, the left sidebar says "You have not opened a folder". OmniSharp will look in your currently opened folder for project files.

1. Add your folder.  File > Open Folder...
2. Make sure you have a project file (either project.json or your *.csproj files).

This should be enough for OmniSharp to start providing you Intellisense.

Comment: Creating a launch.json file also speeded up IntelliSense for my Flutter project. IntelliSense is opening immediately now.

Answer (score 29):

To activate IntelliSense on a .NET project:

1. Open project folder: File->Open folder...
2. Click on the flame on your bottom left corner, pick your project [image: click on the flame]
3. IntelliSense activated!
   [image: IntelliSense is now activated!]

From what I've seen, IntelliSense cannot be activated on a .cs file alone.
(See @natemcmaster's answer).

Comment: Maybe the reason for my problem is what you said, I just edited a single .cs file, not a project.

Comment: @CokileChui natemcmaster's answer is pretty much the reason. OmniSharp needs a project to work on. You may also have to install Mono frameworks on Mac OSX in order to debug the code. But with other script languages like Javascript, it will just fine on a single file.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the `editor.quickSuggestions` setting to `true` in the *settings.json* file. The settings file may be found in:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json

Mac: $HOME/Library/Application Support/User/settings.json

Linux: $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

Comment: Unfortunately, the default value of `editor.quickSuggestions` is `true`. I have submit the problem as a bug to Microsoft.

Comment: I was looking for a language agnostic answer and this answer helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to pick up the language type from the bar at the bottom (the button with the flame).

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had 2 versions installed.  I was launching from the command prompt and it kept running the older version.  In Programs and Features, I removed the one that didn't have "(user)" at the end of the application name, and when I opened Code again, it started downloading packages, one of which was OmniSharp, and then IntelliSense started working.

Note that I was also getting the following warning when opening the older version, and searching for the warning led me to instructions on removing the other version, which in turn fixed the IntelliSense problem:

*You are running the system-wide installation of Code, while having the user-wide distribution installed as well. Make sure you're running the Code version you expect.*

Answer (score 0):

Issue :
if i hit <kbd>!</kbd> it was not showing any suggestion(emmet), i also tried to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> its was showing "no suggestions". i tried to uninstall and re- install vs code several times but seems its picking the previous settings somehow(for example old extensions are pre loaded with every fresh install).

So, i went to below path and deleted .vscode folder and it fixed the issue.

Steps:

1. uninstall vscode
2. go to below path
   C:\Users<user_name_of_the_system>\
   and delete .vscode folder
3. restart the system and install vs code

You will be all set..!!

Note : this is applicable only for windows pc