# Is there anyway to get Intellisense on Visual Studio Code to work on individual .cs files?

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-code

There are some code snippets located in individual .cs files that I want to edit in Visual Studio Code. From what I've read, the only way to trigger it is to load a .sln file. Is there any way to enable it temporarily for an individual .cs file?

Comment: Maybe chose C# as language in the bottom right corner? im not sure if it workds though.

Comment: Yes, the file is chosen as C# on the bottom right. Syntax highlighting and everything works, it's just the drop down intellisense when adding a dot after a control, such as Textbox1. with proper namespaces included on top.

Comment: have you tried omnisharp extension for VS Code ?

Comment: I kind of gave up on it. I don't think it will ever work because it needs the project references. Just loaded it as a class library project.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before so the following link provides some suggestions to help you in getting intellisense in Visual Studio Code. Hopefully that will help.

[Visual Studio Code IntelliSense suggestions don't pop up automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616394/visual-studio-code-intellisense-suggestions-dont-pop-up-automatically)