# VS Code Intellisense doesn't work for nuget packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, nuget

Setup :

- dotnet core 2.2
- Visual studio code Insiders 1.33.0

VS Code Extensions :

- C# 1.17.1
- NuGet Package Manager 1.1.6

For a school project I must use ADO.NET to access the Database.
So I added the nuget package System.Data.SqlClient with the nuget extension.
Here is the result of my csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.2"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.7.0-preview3.19128.7"/>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Useful.Utilities" Version="1.0.5"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The problem is that there is no Intellisense.

[When I want to do a using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMtXl.png)

[SqlCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdAdf.png)

But it's working on Visual Studio Community Version 16.0.0 RC2

[Add a using with Intellisense working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KzXo.png)

[SqlCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUr2V.png)

The problem occur not only with System.Data.SqlClient but with all nuget package I added.

What should I do to have a working Intellisense on Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: Check your settings => Editor -> All Languages
or reset your settings :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616394/visual-studio-code-intellisense-suggestions-dont-pop-up-automatically

Comment: I have reset my settings and extensions and it's working ! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

*To elevate @xqlimax's comment to an answer, since I had this same problem and the comment solved it:*

If the project that contains package references is in a *subfolder* of the folder currently open in VSCode, Intellisense doesn't seem to pick up package references from that project.

Instead, **open the folder that contains the project directly.**

When working with Dev Containers, if you have your Dev Container config in a parent folder but want to work with a project in a subfolder, you can use [this trick](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/configure-separate-containers):

> Once connected *[to the container]* use `File > Open... / Open Folder...` to select one of the *[subfolders]*.
> In a moment, VS Code will open the folder inside the same container. In the future, you can use the Remote Explorer in the Activity Bar to open this sub-folder in the container directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can reset settings and extensions, and if that does not not help, do a clean VS install

Comment: I have reset my settings after that the intellisense worked but when I restart my computer the intellisense was no longer working... I figured out why, this is because I opened the Parent Folder of the folder my project and not the folder of the project. It's silly but now it's working well.

Comment: I did the same thing working with VSCode Dev Containers. I just opened the project folder in VSCode instead of the parent Dev container folder and everything is fine now. Thank you. This really should be the answer to this question.