# No Intellisense in VS Code's Python Debug Console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm moving from PyCharm to Visual Studio Code. PyCharm's debugger has an "evaluate expression" option which is quite handy. VS Code's Debug Console is a decent alternative to that. Unfortunately, intellisense does not seem to be working there.

Is there any way to enable intellisense in the debug console window?

Comment: Does intelliSense work in the editor? Or it doesn't work in either the debug console nor the editor?

Comment: It works in the editor. It isn't perfect but it's working.

Comment: What extension did you install?? Mine is [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and it works perfectly in both. I suggest installing it if not installed.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616394/visual-studio-code-intellisense-suggestions-dont-pop-up-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliSense is automatically provided in the debug console when using the Python extension for VS Code. If it isn't working then please file a bug at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.